# Change the background color of an element inside `setInterval`

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I'm trying to make an `<h1>` element's color change every 300 ms by using `document.getElementById("h1").style` and making it a variable that makes a random color, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
var newColor = getRandomColor();
function color() {
    document.getElementById("h1").style = "backgroundColor = " + newColor;
    setTimeout(color(), 300)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few pointers:

- You can't use the tag name (`h1`) as the argument to `getElementById` unless you set one in your HTML (which I would recommend renaming);
- You need to use `element.style.backgroundColor = newColor` to update CSS styling;
- You need to omit the parentheses after `color()` when you pass a function to `setTimeout` (otherwise you are passing the *return value* of that function);
- You should be calling `getRandomColor` inside your color function, so you get a different color each time;
- You can use `setInterval` instead of recursively calling `setTimeout` inside `color`, and since `setInterval` can pass extra parameters to your callback function you don't need to save your `<h1>` in a global variable.

**Edit:** You can drastically shorten your `getRandomColor` function by using JavaScript's native hex string conversion: `number.toString(16)`

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
function getRandomColor () {
  return '#' + (
    '000000' + (Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16)
  ).slice(-6)
}

function color (heading) {
  heading.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
}

setInterval(color, 300, document.getElementById('heading'))
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

(function color() {
    document.getElementById("myH1").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    
    //if you want to query element by tag name
    //document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    setTimeout(color, 300)
})();
```

```css
#myH1{
 transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myH1">test</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
document.getElementById("h1").style = "backgroundColor = " + newColor;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("h1").style.backgroundColor = + newColor;
```

This code is untested, but `backgroundColor` is a property of style so it should be `style.backgroundColor` not `style = backgroundColor`.

**EDIT**

As another answer mentioned as well, h1 can't be a property of getElementById so give your h1 an Id or select it using a different method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   }
   return color;
}

setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}, 300)
```